# problema con archivo en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy compilando este codigo HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="javascript/archivo_script.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <p>estamos estudiando javascript 1</p>
    <p>estamos estudiando javascript 2</p>
    <p>estamos estudiando javascript 3</p>
</body>

<script src="javascript/archivo_script.js"></script>
</html>
```

y este codigo en JAVASCRIPT

```
function ejecuta(){
    document.getElementsByTagName("p")[2].onclick=saludo(); 
}
function saludo(){
    alert("Que hay de nuevo"); 
}
window.onload=ejecuta();
```

El problema es que quiero que al dar click a cada etiqueta `<p>` muestre `alert` pero me muestra primero `alert` automaticamente cuando compilo el codigo .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema aquí es que `getElementsByTagName()` te devuelve un array de los elementos `p`, y para asignar un listener a cada uno de esos elementos debes recorrerlos.

Por ejemplo aquí, con el `for` recorremos los elementos, asignando a cada uno el listener:

```js
function ejecuta() {
  /*Referencia al array*/
  let allP = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  
  /*Asignamos el listener a c/elemento*/
  for (var i = 0; i < allP.length; i++) {
    allP[i].addEventListener('click', saludo, false);
  }
}

function saludo(e) {
  alert(`Que hay de nuevo Soy el p: ${e.target.textContent}`);
}

/*Puede que sea mejor usar document en vez de window*/
document.onload = ejecuta();
```

```html
<p>estamos estudiando javascript 1</p>
<p>estamos estudiando javascript 2</p>
<p>estamos estudiando javascript 3</p>
```